# How to view new product to frontend when there is new record in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 problem with mysql and php.

I have one table named products

```
 ------------------------------
|  id  |  name                 |
 ------------------------------
| 1    | Product 1             |
 ------------------------------
| 2    | Product 2             |
 ------------------------------
```

and my view is

```
1: Product 1
2: Product 2
```

My problem is:

> If someone insert new record in table products, I want to show in view without refreshing.
>   And I don't want to use aJax to request in any specific period

Do any body know about this, please guide me?

Best Regards,

Comment: Can't be done without some call back to the server. You'll have to use Ajax or reload the page.  If you go the reload method, you can use a javascript timer to reload the page on a regular schedule.

Comment: You can use a Websocket to allow the server to update the view without making a callback, but it will be overkill for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't have any experience about this. Please tell me more!

Comment: http://ape-project.org/ 
take a look, this might be of help

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript `autorefresh` function which will refresh your page after particular      interval of time as follows.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
     setInterval(page_refresh, 5*60000); //refresh in 5 min.
 </script>
```